# Unable to parse abbreviated day name from string

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I'm trying to parse a date in my string using DateTime.TryParseExact. The string looks like this:

```
Wed, 21 Apr 2019 07:28:45 GMT
```

However, the parse function always fails when I use the [ddd format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#dddSpecifier). If I remove `'Wed'` from the string and the `'ddd'` part from the format string, it parses just fine.

Here's a bit of code that reproduces the problem

```cs
var ci = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB");
var datesToParse = new[] { "Wed, 21 Apr 2019 07:28:45 GMT", "21 Apr 2019 07:28:45 GMT" };
var formats = new[] { "ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'", "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'" };

foreach (var dateToParse in datesToParse)
{
    var result = DateTime.TryParseExact(dateToParse, formats, ci, DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces, out DateTime parsedDate)
        ? parsedDate.ToLongDateString()
        : $"Unable to parse date: {dateToParse}";

    Console.WriteLine(result);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

And the output:

```
Unable to parse date: Wed, 21 Apr 2019 07:28:45 GMT
21 April 2019
```

I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong here. Any help would be appreciated.

edit: improved the output and program syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that 21 April 2019 was a Sunday and not a Wednesday. This works fine `"Sun, 21 Apr 2019 07:28:45 GMT"`

Comment: Yes, I figured that out just now. Such a silly mistake to make!